# SolrNet building a compound query

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am trying to build the following query using SolrNet.

```
(type:Contact) AND ((firstName:Jason)^100) OR ((lastName: Winters)^100)
```

I have tried to use the following code:

```
var query = new SolrQuery("type:Contact") &&
            new SolrQuery("firstName:Jason").Boost(100) ||
            new SolrQuery("lastName:Winters").Boost(100);
```

Looking at the Catalina log in Tomcat, the following query was produced, the nested brackets is not what I expected, is this correct?

```
q=((type:Contact+AND+(firstName:Jason)^100)+OR+(lastName:Winters)^100)
```

Also, it would be perfect if I can embed this search logic using a request handler in Solr configuration, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Consider posting to the SolrNet mailing list instead: http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/solrnet . Due to repeated censorship by Stackoverflow moderators, I won't be answering questions here any more.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, will post in the group instead.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/solrnet/NSfX31acJ5M/discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mauricio's link in the comments answers this question.

http://groups.google.com/d/topic/solrnet/NSfX31acJ5M/discussion